# Не получается read_csv в google colab

Tags: python, парсер, машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook

уже почти всё перепробовал... Никак не получается нормально открыть этот csv-шник: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q3lCw_8Uad_OzHCjvLeYRvamXR74UPbW/view

1. `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv")` получает `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 121535` (при этом тот же самый код с просто read_csv всё корректно считывает в Jupyter Lab)
2. Пробую `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` Получаю `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6`
3. Новая попытка: `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep='\t')`. Тут уже ошибки нет, но в результате получается 1 слипшаяся колонка FullDescription,SalaryNormalized,в которой данные тоже слиплись, должно быть 2 колонки в результате: в FullDescription все описания, в SalaryNormalized зарплаты
4. Пробую `dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep=',')` теперь получаю `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6`

В общем никак не хочет работать. При этом в Jupyter Lab всё открывается корректно обычным `pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv")`. Помогите пофиксить, пожалуйста =(

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось без проблем прочитать с `encoding='utf-8'`

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("salary_dataset.csv", encoding='utf-8')

print(dataset.keys())
```

Вывело в консоль `Index(['FullDescription', 'SalaryNormalized'], dtype='object')`

```
print(dataset['SalaryNormalized'])
```

Вывело

```
0         55000
1         27500
2         72098
3         32400
4         67500
          ...  
199995    17161
199996    26000
199997    28500
199998    25000
199999    65000
Name: SalaryNormalized, Length: 200000, dtype: int64
```